# Why doesn't the following clone a vector?

Tags: java

We have a vector `a` of the type `double[]` and we want to clone the values in a to another vector. Why doesn't this work: `double [] b = a;`?

Comment: Because `a` and `b` are merely references to the vector, not the vector itself.  You only copy the reference.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: This might help:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-clone-method-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: Did arrays in Java get renamed to vectors while I was asleep?

Comment: Please, stop asking java's basics before doing some research... You get comment about references in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66629722/why-does-this-conde-snippet-produce-the-following-output question and still you don't get it

Answer (score 1):

A vector in Java when passed to a function or copied into a variable like this, does not copy the values into the new array but rather just references the original object. This code should compile (if a exists as a double vector) but any changes made to a or b will affect the other vector.

The reason this was done is that cloning an object is a very expensive operation and even sometimes impossible. It is safer just to pass references around and let the user create a new object if they need one. In Java, vectors are an object so the property holds.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're just copying a reference to the same array.

```
double[] d1 = {1,2,3,4};
double[] d2 = d1;
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(d1));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(d2));
```

prints

```
135721597
135721597
```

Same identityHashCode so same array.  Changing an element in one array will affect the other array.

But if you want to clone the array. You can do the following:

```
double[] d1 = {1,2,3,4};
double[] d2 = d1.clone();
d1[0] = 99; // to show they're different arrays.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d2));
```

Prints

```
[99.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

However, if the arrays contain Objects, then the arrays are different but the Objects are not cloned.

```
Object[]  d1 = {new Object(), new Object()};
Object[] d2 = d1.clone();
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(d1));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(d2));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(d1[0]));
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(d2[0]));
```

Prints something like

```
135721597
142257191

135721597
135721597
```